# MsBuild create .zip package for solution with multiple projects

Tags: msbuild

I am have Solution with multiple projects. When I run MSbuild with the following Arguments

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /target:Publish /p:Configuration=Release
```

it compiles and puts the compiled code in _PublishedWebsites folder. what arguments needs to be added so that packages are created for each project.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "Package" target. It creates in zip packages or archivedirs if $(PackageAsSingleFile)==False. "Package" target works only for Web apps